# Microphone does not work on some of Mac devices using maccatalist

Tags: ios, macos, microphone, mac-catalyst

I am using speech framework in mac-catalist application its working correctly in iOS but it doesn't work on some of the Mac devices. It's working fine on system A its not working on system B but all the logs (debug console) are same even settings/permissions are same. Code is correct as it's working on some of the devices so it couldn't be wrong.

Could anyone please help me to track the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is system A and system B running different versions of macOs? (I wanted to comment, but I don't have enough rep yet)

Comment: @user14243629 Thanks for your comment. No both the systems have same Mac version 10.15.5

Answer (score 1):

While you've verified that both have the same settings / permissions have you ensured the accessibility within the 'System Preferences' has been granted access for your specific application? Sometimes this can be found within 'System Preferences' -> 'Security & Privacy' -> 'Accessibility'.

Sometimes running your program via `sudo ./your-application` can prompt this security requirement, so attempt running the application in `sudo` and checking the security settings once more.